# Popen stdout value

Tags: python, subprocess, code-injection, popen

im doing a ctf challenge about an SSTI. The solution payload is

```
{{"".__class__.__mro__[1].__subclasses__()[213](['cat','flag.txt'],stdout=-1).communicate()}}
```

I would like to know why stdout accepts -1 as a value. I could not find it in the current subprocess documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-1` is just the value of [`subprocess.PIPE`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/subprocess.py#L259)

```
PIPE = -1
```

Given the convoluted nature of getting a reference to `Popen` in the first place, `subprocess.PIPE` itself may not be available, so its value is used instead.

Comment: ty, it makes sense